# Merging two collections only returns one

Tags: php, laravel

I have two laravel collections (posts and events), I merge both into a new cllection called sliderItems, hoever this collection only returns one of the collections intead of a merged one with both, in this case only posts.

```
$sliderPosts = Post::where('isFeatured', true)->where('isVisible', true)->with('postcategory')->latest()->get();
        //dump($sliderPosts);
        $sliderEvents = Event::where('isFeatured', true)->where('isVisible', true)->latest()->get();
        //dump($sliderEvents);
        $sliderItems = $sliderEvents->merge($sliderPosts)->take(4);
        //dump($sliderItems);
```

Comment: Not sure how the merge logic works, but I would think that `->take(4);` is taking the first 4 elements, which might be only `Post` models. If you remove the `->take(4);`, does it contain everything?

Comment: please, post what the collections are (what showing the dumps) like and what you expect from the merge

Answer (score 0):

you are merging two collections and taking only 4 objects, do like this,

```
$sliderPosts = Post::where('isFeatured', true)->where('isVisible', true)->with('postcategory')->latest()->take(2);
//dump($sliderPosts);
$sliderEvents = Event::where('isFeatured', true)->where('isVisible', true)->latest()->take(2);
//dump($sliderEvents);
$sliderItems = $sliderEvents->merge($sliderPosts);
//dump($sliderItems);
```